# How does C++ know that an increment ++ is prefix or postfix when overloading the operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, increment, prefix, postfix-mta

I understand how to make prefix and postfix incrementers. Within my class DoStuff, I have:

```
// Prefix; returns the incremented value
friend const DoStuff& operator++(DoStuff& a);
// Postfix: returns the incremented value
friend const DoStuff operator++(DoStuff& a, int);
```

and outside the class, I have

```
const DoStuff& operator++(DoStuff& a){
    a.num++;
    return a;
}

const DoStuff operator++(DoStuff& a, int){
    DoStuff before(a.num);
    a.num++;
    return before;
}
```

for the prefix and postfix incrementers respectively. What I don't understand is how C++ knows that the former is represented by `++a` and the latter `a++`. As far as I can tell, the prefix incrementer references the address `&` and that somehow means that the `++` operator symbol should come before it. 
Also, I'm not too sure why the postfix needs an `int` variable.

Comment: It knows because the standard says so, see [[over.inc](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.inc#:postfix_++_and_--,overloading)].

Comment: The dummy `int` is used to distinguish.  It's optimized away.

Comment: Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421729/4342498) your operators should be members and not global functions.  You should really check out the while Q&A there as it covers pretty much everything to do with operator overloading.

Comment: Why are questions like this downvoted? This seems like a well asked question by a new member. Should this not be encouraged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the compiler reads your source code, it can figure out whether you've used a prefix or a postfix. Very simple: either the `++` comes up before or after some object.

Then the compiler will generate code to call the right function. But what's the name of that function? The people that designed C++ decided to make the function name for overloaded operators `operator` followed by the operator you're overloading (`++`, `--`, `=` etc), like `operator*`, `operator-`, etc.

But the problem now is that both prefix and postfix increment operators are named `operator++`. How do you differentiate between them? When you encounter `++var` and `var++`, the compiler generates code to call `operator++` for both of them, but you don't want that because now you can't differentiate between the definitions between a postfix and a prefix increment operator.

To solve this, the same language designers added a dummy parameter, `int`. This way, the compiler can call `operator++(0)`, or `operator++(42)` (or whatever number you feel like, it's not important. It's a dummy parameter) when it encounters a postfix `++`, and just an `operator++()` when it encounters a prefix. The parameter is just there for differentiation.

All in all, this is a language design problem. When it comes to design decisions, naturally, there must've been other solutions (like naming them `operator_preinc()` and `operator_postinc()`), but this is what the designers of C++ chose to go with. They could have their reasons, or it could be arbitrarily chosen because maybe all other options weigh about the same.